# Normalizing group data for correlation

Tags: correlation, sample-size, normalization, group-differences

Say I own gas stations across the entire north east and my total territory is broken down into regions. Some regions may have 100 gas stations and others may have 500. So the regions that have 500 stores will have much higher sales than the other regions. 
Although there is this difference I would like to correlate sales to customer satisfaction. How do I normalize the sales data to show the relationship? At the company level, when I correlate all sales to satisfaction, there is a clear relationship but I would like to prove this out at a more granular level.

Update:

All I am trying to do is correlate net sals with customer satisfaction.
You can see that every year sales increases  AND customer satisfaction increases year over year. This is not seen in the correlation coefficient because net sales is much higher for regions with more stores even though sales improves with customer satisfaction.

```
year    n       Region               Net Sales           Customer Sat %
2015    100     region1             $800,000,000.00          72
2015 500 region2             $3,000,000,000.00           73
2015    150     region3             $1,000,000,000.00           72
2014 100 region1             $600,000,000.00                 68
2014    500     region2             $2,800,000,000.00           67
2014 150 region3             $900,000,000.00             70
```

Comment: What level is your data broken down to? Regions as well, or do you have individual store-level data?

Comment: @Ian_Fin could break it down to the store-level as well. But at the store level I lose the relationship

Comment: can you perhaps edit your question to give some specifics about the analyses you've already run? It's not 100% clear what you're looking to do.

Comment: @Ian_Fin updated

Comment: Thanks. How is time factoring into the correlation that you discuss? Are you treating region1's sales and customer satisfaction in 2015 as independent from their 2014 figures?

Comment: @Ian_Fin At this point I would like to treat the correlation as a cross sectional analysis where I correlate sales and customer satisfaction. I've seen issues like this with [crime](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/13468/datatx) where rates of crime for different areas with different populations are compared.

Comment: You may want to investigate multilevel modeling. If I was trying to investigate whether sales correlated with customer satisfaction then I'd regress customer satisfaction onto sales and time, using region as a random effect.

Comment: @Ian_Fin I'm familiar with mixed models and thought that would be the next step after a correlation. What coefficient in the mixed model would you use to state the correlation?

Comment: If you mean the correlation coefficient (in the strictest sense) then I'm not sure you can get that. If you mean simply identifying that a correlation exists (and its sign) then the coefficient associated with customer satisfaction